# TF IDF using dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I calculated tf and idf for all terms in documents, so I have two objects:
1) tf  dictionaries(there are about 10k):

```
{'doc_1': {'rain':0.4, 'sun':0.6}}
{'doc_2': {'............
{'doc_3': {'rain':0.1, .......
```

2) idf ONE single dictionary:

```
{'rain': 0.18, 'sun': 0.12......
```

3) I have my list index for all terms:

```
[{'term1':[[doc_1, 2],[doc_2, 3]]}, {'term2': [[doc_6, 6],[doc3,1]]}
```

....and so on for every term

How can I calculate `tf*idf` now for example for a list of words? I was trying:

```
def tf_idf(list_of words): 
    t_id={}
    for i in list_of_words:
        score= {}
        for j in terms: 
            score[j[0]]=(idf[i]*tf[j[0]][i])
        t_id[i]=score
    return t_id
```

it give me an error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Some general programming advice here:

```
def tf_idf(list_of words, tf, idf):   # Pass your variables in, as opposed to using the global scope. 
    t_id={}
    for word in list_of_words:  # Name your variables to avoid confusion
        score= {}
        for term in terms: 
            score[term[0]]=(idf[word]*tf[term[0]][word])
        t_id[i]=score
    return t_id
```

I *think* your issue here is in referring to `term[0]` (you had this as `j[0]`).   According to your post, `terms` looks like this:

```
[{'term1':[[doc_1, 2],[doc_2, 3]]}...]
```

So `term` (or `j`) is just:

```
{'term1':[[doc_1, 2],[doc_2, 3]]}
```

When you refer to `term[0]` (or `j[0]`), there would need to be an element in that dictionary with `0` as its key.

Since that key is missing, you get a KeyError.

Comment: now it gives : score[term[0]]=(idf[word]*tf[term[0]][word])

KeyError: '1'

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the programming advice from ers81239. I analysed your program and I saw the same mistakes. So the real answer to your actual question is that you can't given your data structures.

However, to get you started, I rewrote it from scratch, trying to interpret your intentions from your code.

First, the term frequencies contain al information. I changed that into a nested dict and then calculated idf. This leaves you with less data structures and less places to mis-index.

From that it is not hard to calculate the TF*IDF. I left out as much as possible.

```
from collections import Counter
from math import log

tf = {
        'term1': {'doc_1': 2, 'doc_2': 3},
        'term2': {'doc_2': 6, 'doc_3': 1},
}

N = float(len({k for doc_freqs in tf.itervalues()
                   for k in doc_freqs.iterkeys()}))

print N

idf = {term: N/len(doc_freqs)
           for term, doc_freqs in tf.iteritems()}

print idf


tf_idf = {term: tf[term][doc] * idf[term]
             for term, doc_freqs in tf.iteritems()
                for doc in doc_freqs}

print tf_idf
```

Please keep in mind that this is the simplest TF*IDF one can imagine and lots of improvements are generally applied.